# What is the idiomatic way of getting an integer value from query string in Echo?

Tags: go, go-echo

I have an integer query param "page", that defaults to 1. I can get it from Echo context like this:

```
var page int
pageString := c.QueryParam("page")
if pageString == "" {
    page = 1
} else {
    var err error
    page, err = strconv.Atoi(pageString)

    if err != nil {
        page = 1
    }
}
```

While this works, I would kind of prefer to do something like `page := c.QueryParamInt("page", 1)` but I couldn't find any equivalent in Echo docs. Should I just write my own utility function or is there a better way?

Comment: You could do something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/fu66E8wMtfX but other than that, you'll have to write your own utility functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like:

```
qp := c.QueryParam("page")
page, err := strconv.Atoi(qp)
if err != nil {
        page=1
}
```

You don't have to write that much ifelse.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on parsing many integer params then the best thing would be to write your own utility function:

```golang
func QueryParamInt(c echo.Context, name string, default int) int {
  param := c.QueryParam(name)
  result, err := strconv.Atoi(param)
  if err != nil {
    return default
  }
  return result
}
```

Then use it as you would like.
Other options would be to extend the echo context, more on that [here](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/context).